# Google Play subscription missing, but can be restored by clearing cache of Google Store

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-services

I develop android app that has Play Billing version 6.0.1 implemented which gives users additional features. For most users it works very well. But some of them do have problem that the app do not see the subscription from time to time. For example I have an OnePlus Nord user that bought subscription it worked for some time, but when he updated the app to new version the billing stopped working. It starts working again when he clears Google Play, Google Services cache. And we have bunch of other similar cases. Clearing Google Play Services, Google Play Store cache very often helps. Why the error is happening? And is it possible to avoid it and do not disturb users with this problem. To assure user that he always has subscription when he buys it?

Additional info: There is also a lot of cases when the billing is not working because of "Billing connection failed: Google Play In-app Billing API version is less than 3 Response code: 3." although the user is working with billing library 6.0.1, on a new device, with Android 13 and the latest version of Google Play.